# Simple Electric Shock Device

Tags: high-voltage, piezoelectricity

Can anyone tell me how to make a simple electric shocking device (like a electric pen or hand buzzer style). I've seen people use piezoelectric elements from lighters (is that correct?) but I would like to know how to create one from scratch, and also what current and voltage is needed to give a small shock. Thanks, ell.

Comment: electronics should be used for good and not evil

Comment: no schematic but i think this is more of what your looking for? http://planetstephanie.net/2010/12/07/owbox/ you should be able to figure out how it works, but pretty much just a 555 timer 9v battery and a few other components.

Comment: @vicatcu, evil and good are often determined by whom you use the tool on, not the tool. For example, if I were to shock @tyblu, that would be good, but @pingswept and I get scolded.

Comment: @Kortuk... wow, never thought of it that way lol

Comment: @Kortuk: Wait, why do I get scolded just because you're testing your "Touch of God" machine on @tyblu? I'm innocent!

Comment: @pingswept no, you would scold Kortuk if he were to test it on you.

Comment: @kellenjb: Ah, I misunderstood. That's a relief. I was worried I was complicit in shocking @tyblu.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is actually quite a simple circuit which works by stepping up the collapse of a magnetic field in a small audio transformer.

The schematic looks like this:

[image: schematic]

I think something [like this part](http://search.digikey.com/scripts/DkSearch/dksus.dll?Detail&name=MT4135-ND) should work for the transformer.

If you touch the two output wires, you'll get a very small electric shock as you release the push button.

Comment: god I love stack exchange

Comment: When I was a kid some 50 years ago I built something like this using a Model T spark coil -- then attached the output to a doorknob handle.

Comment: And this is safe to zap people with, right? Causing no permanent or serious damage? Thanks, that is very helpful! I always like to seek advice for potentially dangerous projects

Comment: @tcrosley - didn't those make inch long sparks? that must have been quite a surprise for someone.

Comment: @Eli - Yes, it's safe because you only have *E = 1/2 * C * V^2* ~= 0.1 millijoules of energy stored in the cap.

Comment: @JustJeff -- yes, about that and very visible.  Yes, it was a quite a "shock" for someone.

Comment: "The effects of electrical current passing through the human body are covered at length in the International Electro Technical Commission document IEC 479-2:1987. In this document it indicates that a transient or capacitive discharge, as is the case with static electricity, requires energy in excess of 5 Joules (5000mJ) to produce a direct serious risk to health."  http://www.wolfsonelectrostatics.com/04_news/index.html

Comment: EN 60065 limits the maximum energy of a discharge to 350 mJ for safety certification.

Comment: could you please explain "works by stepping up the collapse of a magnetic field in a small audio transformer"

Comment: In the DigiKey link provided below the circuit diagram above, note that it isn't the part pictured in the diagram, it's a 600:600 ohm transformer, and probably wouldn't work. While also not the part pictured, this might work better. http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/tamura/MET-35/MT4153-ND/285670